# How to make specific request by using Wiremock?

Tags: json, wiremock

I try to practice creating mock data with Wiremock and send JSON body request like this

---

> { "petId ":"123"}

---

When petId is 123, 124, 125

It should show response request is

---

> { "petType":"1",
> "wildLevel":"40"}

---

When petId is 250, 251, 252

---

> { "petType":"2", "wildLevel":"80"}

---

and I create mapping JSON

---

```
{
  "mappings": [
{
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPath": "/mock/animal/status",
        "bodyPatterns": [
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '123')]",
            "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '124')]",
            "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '125')]",
          }
        ]
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "transformers": ["response-template"],
        "bodyFileName": "animal-success-40-200.json",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    },
{
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPath": "/mock/animal/status",
        "bodyPatterns": [
          {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '250')]",
            "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '251')]",
            "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '252')]",
          }
        ]
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "transformers": ["response-template"],
        "bodyFileName": "animal-success-80-200.json",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    }
]
}
```

---

but it works just petID 125 and 252 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [OR operator](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#logical-and-and-or).

```
...
"bodyPatterns": [
  {
    "OR": [
      { "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '250')]" },
      { "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '251')]" },                      
      { "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '252')]" },
    ]
  },
...
```

You could also simplify your `matchesJsonPath` logic to only include a single regex for each, something like...

```
...
"matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType =~ /25(0|1|2)/)]"
...
```

Look at the `Regex Matching` examples under the [JSON Path documentation.](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#json-path)

Comment: Excellent ! Thx <3

Comment: Excuse , but I just have tine to re-run my code
I use the solution
"bodyPatterns": [
  {
    "OR": [
      { "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '250')]" },
      { "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '251')]" },                      
      { "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.petType== '252')]" },
    ]
  },

but this code doesn't work for me :[ 
It show  "is not a valid match operation"

Comment: Which version of WireMock are you using?

Comment: WIREMOCK_VERSION 2.27.2 and TRANSFORMER_VERSION 1.1.6

Comment: AND and OR operators were added in 2.28.0. Can you upgrade WireMock (to at least 2.28.0) and trying again?

Comment: It already worked when I update new version and change "OR" to "or". Thank you agoff!!